# install chrome extension without publishing on chrome web store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, google-chrome-app

I am figuring out ways to install chrome extensions on windows machines without hosting extension on chrome web store. I found a way to use windows registry but seems like there also update url should also be from chrome web store(attached links below for reference). Is there any other alternative to install extensions on user machines without hosting it on web store.
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/external_extensions#preferences
https://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html.

Note that I don't need it for development purpose.It is for the users who want to test the extension before we publish release it

Comment: As a fast way workaround, you can tell the users to activate chrome developer mode and just use the unpacked file, that should work fine...